# ServiceNow - client script getReference dot walk

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-client-scripts

So I'm using `g_form.getReference('server')` which is a reference field to `cmdb_ci_server` and I need to get the name of the server location. However I only get a hex value back when I look at the location. I need to show a couple fields about the server the user picked out to ensure they got the right one.

How do I translate the hex value into a usable name inside of a client script?

I would rather not implement a script include just to get this single value back.